# How do I get all unique documents by a max field

Tags: solr, liferay, solr4, liferay-solr

I am working on a search feature for a Liferay 6.2 app, but I am struggling with how to get the latest articles.

For reasons, the client wants to track all versions of the Liferay Journal Articles in Solr.  This means that every "version" gets stored as a separate document with an incrementing `version` field.  For the purpose of the search, I need to grab the latest one.

For example, if I have a Journal Article like this in Solr:

`[{
   articleId:"123456",
   title:"Sample Doc 1",
   content:"abc 123 xyz",
   version:"1.0"
},
{
   articleId:"222111",
   title:"Sample Doc 2",
   content:"1111",
   version:"1.0"
},
{
   articleId:"222111",
   title:"Sample Doc 2",
   content:"2222",
   version:"1.1"
},
{
   articleId:"123456",
   title:"Sample Doc 1",
   content:"xxx xxx 1234556",
   version:"1.1"
},
{
   articleId:"222111",
   title:"Sample Doc 2",
   content:"3333",
   version:"1.2"
}]`

And I queried all documents I would expect the results:

`[{
   articleId:"123456",
   title:"Sample Doc 1",
   content:"xxx xxx 1234556",
   version:"1.1"
},
{
   articleId:"222111",
   title:"Sample Doc 2",
   content:"3333",
   version:"1.2"
}]`

Noticing that I only retrieved each unique `articleId` that had the max `version`.

Exact versions I am working on are:
  Liferay 6.2.ee sp11 (with some patches)
  Solr 4.10.4 under Tomcat 7.0.64

I tried googling for answers, but I am not sure what I am googling for here.  I don't think facets are the answer, and grouping doesn't seem to return the results I need.

Comment: Shouldn't grouping by articleId and sorting the group by version work? (but keep in mind - if the version is actually a string, 1.2 will sort _after_ 1.10)

Answer (score 1):

You can use grouping or a [collapse filter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collapse+and+Expand+Results) for that. From my experience collapse filter is much faster than grouping. Here is how it should be used for your case:

```
fq={!collapse field=articleId max=version}
```